# merge two or more lists get unique combinations with same length and statistics

Tags: python-3.x, python-itertools

```
l1=[1,1,2,3,5,6,6]
l2 = [2,2,1,1,5,6]
```

then return one of the possibility [(1,2),(1,1),(2,2),(3,2),(5,1),(6,5),(6,6) ]
so same statistics of l1 and l2 used with unique combinations. Number of lists can be 2 or more

length of l1 and l2 is 6
length of final result also 6

i thought of using itertools module  , but maintaining same statistics in each list is difficult.

Comment: are you looking for all the unique combinations between items from l1 and items from l2? in your example, is (6,2) a valid combination?

Comment: yes (6,2) is valid combination , so the result can be like this [(1,2),(1,1),(6,2),(3,2),(5,1),(6,5),(2,6) ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import itertools

l1 = [1,1,2,3,5,6]
l2 = [2,2,1,1,5,6]
found = {}
for perm in itertools.permutations(l1, len(l1)):
    pairs = set(zip(perm, l2))
    if len(pairs) == len(l1):
        found = pairs
        break
print(found if found else "not found")
```

Comment: yes its unique combinations , but number of 1's are in l1 not same as unique combinations, Statistcs of l1 will change in final result.  and expecting result is same length as l1

Comment: are you sure there's always a result with these requirements? suppose l1=[1,1,1,1,1,1] and l2=[2,2,2,2,2,2], then the only unique combination is (1,2), so in that case the result legnth is 1 and not 6 as expected.

Comment: its not possible for your scenario, but provided input to the program is valid one , So we can generate unique combinations. . Here the problem is "maintaining statistics of l1 and l2 at output as same as input"

Comment: check out the updated answer. if the input has a possible solution, this code finds it by iterating over the permutations, removing duplicates (by throwing into a set), and then verifying that the outcome has the expected length.

Comment: @Naveen Bhaskar ^^

Comment: Thanks you , this logic looks works for me . how about if we have more than 2 lists

Comment: for more than 2 lists, the basic concept (using "zip" and "set") still works, but you'll need to check all-permutation-of-list-2 x all-permutation-of-list-3 x ... x all-permutation-of-list-N . I propose to use a recursive function. try writing it, and if you need my help let me know.